# Почему в верстке текст не смещается в центр? Объясните мою ошибку, хочу разобраться

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Текст и желтая линия должны располагаться по центру, как в макете:

[image: как надо]

Но, в итоге, съезжают куда-то вправо:

[image: как у меня]

Три картинки с ноутбуками не выстраиваются в один ряд, а стоят друг за другом в лесенке. В чём моя ошибка? Прошу рассказать с объяснениями, чтобы было понятно.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.promo {
  height: 800px;
  background: url('../img/background/bg.png') center center/cover no-repeat;
  padding: 39px 0 62px 0;
}

.logo .logo_img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo .logo_text {
  /* Style for "WordPress" */
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 53px;
}

.title {
  color: #f9bf3b;
  font-family: 'Roboto - Black';
  font-size: 41px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

h2.title {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.simple .title_big {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto - Black";
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.promo .promo_text {
  padding: 0 13px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto Light";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.promo .promo_text span {
  color: #f9bf3b;
  font-family: "Roboto - Bold";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.promo .promo_btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 73px;
  width: 313px;
  height: 72px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #2798b9 0%, #3ab6da 100%);
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.more {
  margin-top: 73px;
}

.more .more_text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto - Thin";
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.more .more_img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.waiting {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 604px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 85px 0 75px 0;
}

.waiting .waiting_header {
  color: #252525;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.waiting .waiting_divider {
  width: 217px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #f9bf3b;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.waiting .waiting_subheader {
  margin-top: 17px;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

.waiting .waiting_wrapper {
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.waiting .waiting_wrapper .waiting_item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 339px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Wordpress интенсив</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@1,700&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <section class="promo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="icons/owl.png" alt="logo" class="logo_img">
        <div class="logo_text">WordPress интенсив</div>
      </div>

      <h1 class="title">Создать свой сайт на WordPress</h1>
      <div class="simple">
        <h2 class="title_big">это просто!</h2>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="title">Куда сложнее сделать это правильно!</h2>

      <div class="promo_text">
        Ежедневно в России появляется более 5 000 новых сайтов. <br> И только единицы из них становятся популярными и приносят ощутимую прибыль. В чем секрет? В чем формула успеха? Узнайте на предстоящем двухдневном <span>БЕСПЛАТНОМ</span> интенсиве!
      </div>

      <button class="promo_btn">Записаться на интенсив!</button>

      <div class="more">
        <div class="more_text">узнать больше об интенсиве</div>
        <img src="icons/arrow.png" alt="down" class="more_img">
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section class="waiting">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="waiting_header">Что вас ждет в нашем интенсиве?</h2>
      <div class="waiting_divider"></div>
      <div class="waiting_subheader">2 бесплатных полноценных обучающих вебинара, где:</div>

      <div class="waiting_wrapper">
        <div class="waiting_item">
          <img src="img/laptob/1.png" alt="2" class="waiting_img">
          <div class="waiting_desrc">Всего за два бесплатных вебинара мы научим вас, как создать свой сайт на WordPress. </div>
        </div>
        <div class="waiting_item">
          <img src="img/laptob/2.png" alt="2" class="waiting_img">
          <div class="waiting_desrc">Покажем, как правильно оптимизировать сайт и сделать его привлекательным для поисковых систем. Только свежая, профессиональная и актуальная информация!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="waiting_item">
          <img src="img/laptob/3.png" alt="3" class="waiting_img">
          <div class="waiting_desrc">Вы узнаете, что такое «хорошая индексация», «высокая посещаемость», «стабильный прирост посетителей», «ТОП по запросам» и, что намного важнее, как добиться всех этих показателей!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

У класса `.waiting` жёстко прописана ширина, которая больше ширины монитора:

```css
.waiting {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 604px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 85px 0 75px 0;
}
```

Если выставить ширину `.waiting`, как 100% - всё нормально отображается:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.promo {
  height: 800px;
  background: url('../img/background/bg.png') center center/cover no-repeat;
  padding: 39px 0 62px 0;
}

.logo .logo_img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo .logo_text {
  /* Style for "WordPress" */
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 14px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 53px;
}

.title {
  color: #f9bf3b;
  font-family: 'Roboto - Black';
  font-size: 41px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

h2.title {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.simple .title_big {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto - Black";
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.promo .promo_text {
  padding: 0 13px;
  margin-top: 23px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto Light";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.promo .promo_text span {
  color: #f9bf3b;
  font-family: "Roboto - Bold";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.promo .promo_btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 73px;
  width: 313px;
  height: 72px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #2798b9 0%, #3ab6da 100%);
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.more {
  margin-top: 73px;
}

.more .more_text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Roboto - Thin";
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.more .more_img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.waiting {
  width: 100%;
  height: 604px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 85px 0 75px 0;
}

.waiting .waiting_header {
  color: #252525;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.waiting .waiting_divider {
  width: 217px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #f9bf3b;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.waiting .waiting_subheader {
  margin-top: 17px;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

.waiting .waiting_wrapper {
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.waiting .waiting_wrapper .waiting_item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 339px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Wordpress интенсив</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@1,700&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <section class="promo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="icons/owl.png" alt="logo" class="logo_img">
        <div class="logo_text">WordPress интенсив</div>
      </div>

      <h1 class="title">Создать свой сайт на WordPress</h1>
      <div class="simple">
        <h2 class="title_big">это просто!</h2>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="title">Куда сложнее сделать это правильно!</h2>

      <div class="promo_text">
        Ежедневно в России появляется более 5 000 новых сайтов. <br> И только единицы из них становятся популярными и приносят ощутимую прибыль. В чем секрет? В чем формула успеха? Узнайте на предстоящем двухдневном <span>БЕСПЛАТНОМ</span> интенсиве!
      </div>

      <button class="promo_btn">Записаться на интенсив!</button>

      <div class="more">
        <div class="more_text">узнать больше об интенсиве</div>
        <img src="icons/arrow.png" alt="down" class="more_img">
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section class="waiting">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="waiting_header">Что вас ждет в нашем интенсиве?</h2>
      <div class="waiting_divider"></div>
      <div class="waiting_subheader">2 бесплатных полноценных обучающих вебинара, где:</div>

      <div class="waiting_wrapper">
        <div class="waiting_item">
          <img src="img/laptob/1.png" alt="2" class="waiting_img">
          <div class="waiting_desrc">Всего за два бесплатных вебинара мы научим вас, как создать свой сайт на WordPress. </div>
        </div>
        <div class="waiting_item">
          <img src="img/laptob/2.png" alt="2" class="waiting_img">
          <div class="waiting_desrc">Покажем, как правильно оптимизировать сайт и сделать его привлекательным для поисковых систем. Только свежая, профессиональная и актуальная информация!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="waiting_item">
          <img src="img/laptob/3.png" alt="3" class="waiting_img">
          <div class="waiting_desrc">Вы узнаете, что такое «хорошая индексация», «высокая посещаемость», «стабильный прирост посетителей», «ТОП по запросам» и, что намного важнее, как добиться всех этих показателей!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: В макете указаные такие данные серого прямоугольника
Я их просто скопировала и вставила

Comment: Макеты могут быть разной ширины

Comment: @DaryanaS: У Вас `.waiting { width: 1920px; }`, а в нём `.container { width: 1140px; margin: 0 auto; }`. Всё правильно центрируется, но ширина первого явно некорректная.

Comment: Поменяла на 100%. Всё работает, спасибо!

Comment: @DaryanaS: Если ответ помог, то отметьте его)